# Django rest framework Serialzer ForeignKeyField output as field_id

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a Class `Course`, and the model have a foreign key `category`

```
class Course(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

I write the `Serializer` and `View` like:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Course

class CourseViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer
```

when I make a get request, i get the response like:

```
{
    'id':1,
    'category':1,
    'title': 'xxx'
}
```

but what i really want is:

```
{
    'id':1,
    'category_id':1,
    'title': `xxx`
}
```

i want the key be `category_id` instead of `category`. i have tried to specified the name `category_id` in `class Meta in CourseSerializer`, but it doesn't work.

how can i make the code work as i want? thanks!

**Edit**:

also, when make the `post` request for creating a course instance, i want to post the data like:

```
{
    'category_id': 1,
    'title': 'xxx'
}
```

the `key` should also be `category_id`. how can i do this?

Comment: Post your view function and serializer

Comment: @Nivedita thanks for reminding, `serializer` and `view` are above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer, I should use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, and the serializer should be like:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='category', queryset=Category.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Course
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
note : indentation may not be correct here

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        exclude = ['category']

    def get_category_id(self, obj):
        return obj.category.id

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Course.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  `get` really works. but when i use `post`, if failed, and the Exception is `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'category_id' cannot be null")`. has any idea about this? thank you!

Comment: `def get_category_id(self, obj):
    try:
            return obj.category.id
    except obj.DoesNotExist:
         return None`

Comment: no, i think you misunderstand me, i mean when creating a course instance, i use `category_id` in the post data, it won't work. i have updated my question, please check.

Comment: ok now i got you, put create query in try block

try:
    category_obj = Category.object.create() # create category 
    return category_obj.id

Comment: sorry, i can't understand, can you show me more code?

Comment: post your category model

Comment: `class Category(models.Model): name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)`, i have put this into my question

Comment: not this. `category` has already existed, i will only add `category_id` in the my post data. i don't need create category.

Comment: In your post method what are you passing for category ?

Comment: @youmai I got you and I have updated ans check it now.

Comment: Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the  [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) may be what you need:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='id',
                                               queryset=Category.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('category_id',)
```

Let me know if that works!